# Progress bar only runs after method finishes and publishing standalone exe

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is my function. The progress bar only runs after the method readFile.Read has run. Thats okay but that means that when readFile.Read is running, my application looks like its frozen. Is there any way to make it run as my method is running? I can't put it before as if the progress bar is completed and the task isn't, the user might close the application.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    var counter = FileCount / 100;
    var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Input);
    FileCount = files.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < FileCount; i++)
    {
        readFile.Read(files[i], Dictionary, Output);
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(((i+1)*100)/FileCount);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
    ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Also, is there a way to publish my c# application without needing the user to install it? I have found an exe that seems to run fine in the debug/release folder but do I really need all the files? In Java, I'm able to create standalone executables without needing the user the install it. Can I do it here too?

Comment: It's just not painting, try inserting an Application.Doevents after ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

Comment: I read that Doevents might cause bigger issues if the process takes too long. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: ’FileCount/100’ may return 0, as it uses integer division. Plus you set FileCount *after* you calculate count.

Comment: Is the progressbar updating for each file, but 'frozen' during each read? Then use some sort of spinner and/or change the cursor to show that you are working

Comment: `DoEvents()` is not the appropriate way to make a non-responsive UI responsive again. With `Tasks` and the `async`/`await` keywords, almost no refactoring at all is required to keep applications responsive. There's just no need to force the UI thread to process system messages using `DoEvents()` anymore.

Comment: Fair enough, I stopped doing winforms a while back, I just recalled that being the big one.  Great points with async etc, will have to re-visit winforms to try it

Comment: @JianYA Could you show the code where you start the BackgroundWorker?!

Comment: There is no indication that anything is wrong.  If readFile.Read() takes a long time then the code simply won't call ReportProgress() for a long time so there's no progress visible.  A simple way to give an "I'm not dead" indication is to set the ProgressBar.Style property to Marquee.

Answer (score -1):

If your version of .Net supports `System.Threading.Tasks`, I would refactor the method to be asynchronous. You can then use the `async` and `await` keywords to keep the UI responsive and update the `ProgressBar` the same way you would if your program was synchronous. Something like this should work:

```
private async Task DoWorkAsync(string InputDirectory)
{
    var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(InputDirectory);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => readFile.Read(files[i], Dictionary, Output));
        ProgressBar.Value = ((i + 1) * 100) / files.Length;
    }
}
```

With regards to deploying your application, no, you don't have to use an installer. You do need to copy all the `.exe` files and the relevant `.dll` files to each client workstation. You also have to be aware that your clients may not have the correct version of .Net installed. Using an installer greatly simplifies this process.

Comment: (psst, FileStream.ReadAsync is better than shoving a blocking read into a Task)

Comment: @Will it certainly is, but the OP did not provide the implementation details of the `readFile.Read()` method. If they can refactor to use an asynchronous built-in `FileStream` method, they should.